# AS3/Flash How to disable the auto backlight correction in webcam

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, camera, webcam

Im developin an AS3 flash program that use a webcam.

The app gets the bitmaps form this and elaborates.

My problem is that in the first 4-5 seconds the webcam try to correct the backlight and the image is blurry.

There is a method to disactivate this?
If yes, how?

Im getting the wecam with this simple code:

```
cam = Camera.getCamera();
cam.setQuality(0, 80);
cam.setMode(533, 400, 20);
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash has no control over this. And this behaviour may be different with other cams.